# Datatables.net select all rows on table including not shown

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I want to manipulate the dom of all rows on a table but when I use a class to select buttons on my rows, only the 10 rows and the buttons on them shown with pagination will be selectable as jquery objects. Is there a way to select any row on a table regardless of being shown or not?

Answer (score 1):

I'm seeing two different questions here. If you want to **"manipulate"** *all rows* in some way (like adding 100 bucks to a column, etc..), I would do that at the 'source' of my data (array, database table, whatever), then refresh the Datatables. If you simply want to **"select"** any row, you can use the Datatables 'search' functionality. It's pretty well documented at https://datatables.net/reference/api/search() . Am I not understanding your question?

Comment: By manipulate I mean manipulate the dom. Like tr, td and buttons I add to the td cells. If I use search API can I select the buttons by their classes? Looking at the documentation It seems I can only search the value strings in the cells.

Comment: That's correct about the search function -- you'll only be searching the actual values. I wasn't sure of the intent of your question.